# How to find out what is wrong with digital certificate?

Tags: certificate, signature, signing, digital, authenticode

Is there a way to see where exactly is the problem with digital certificate in Windows?

I have bought code signing certificate from CA and I am using it to sign ClickOnce application (using mage.exe) and signing process goes OK.
But, when client is installing my ClickOnce application, the installer warns user that publisher is not verified. I got this to work with self-signed certificate.
I would like to find out where exactly is the problem with this certificate from CA.
Is there any way to "debug" a process of certificate validation (AFAIK that process is Authenticode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authenticode is only the *type* of signature.

Have you double clicked on the certificate that was used to create the signature. The Shell Extension for Windows Explorer might tell you whats wrong - e.g. Untrusted (root/issuer is not in Trusted Certificate Authorities Store), expired, revoked...

Digging deeper (CRL and OCSP):
Revocation checking is done besed of Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL) and Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP).

1. Here is a [white paper](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4954.windows-xp-certificate-status-and-revocation-checking.aspx) for Windows.
2. Using .NET (C#)

```cs
X509Chain ch = new X509Chain();
ch.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
ch.Build (certificate);
Console.WriteLine ("Chain Information");
Console.WriteLine ("Chain revocation flag: {0}", ch.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag);
Console.WriteLine ("Chain revocation mode: {0}", ch.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode);
Console.WriteLine ("Chain verification flag: {0}", ch.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags);
Console.WriteLine ("Chain verification time: {0}", ch.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime);
Console.WriteLine ("Chain status length: {0}", ch.ChainStatus.Length);
Console.WriteLine ("Chain application policy count: {0}", ch.ChainPolicy.ApplicationPolicy.Count);
Console.WriteLine ("Chain certificate policy count: {0} {1}", ch.ChainPolicy.CertificatePolicy.Count, Environment.NewLine);
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.build?view=netframework-4.8

3. DigiCert offers a [tool](https://www.digicert.com/util/) which is is helpful